# Zephyr / PlatformIO / CMake / external code

Tags: cmake, platformio, zephyr-rtos

I'm pretty new to Zephyr and am having trouble adding and compiling code in a sibling folder. This may be further complicated by using PlatformIO, which has a slightly different build structure than the stock Zephyr structure.

The IDE is Visual Studio Code under Windows

The structure of the code is:

```
Parent Folder
|-ext_library (contains CMakeList.txt)
|--source
|--include
|-zephyr_project (structure generated by PlatformIO)
|--zephyr (contains the master CMakeList.txt and prj.conf)
|--source
|--include
|--lib
```

What I want to do is add either source files or a static library from **ext_library** to the **zephyr_project** with out manually copying source / include files or manually building the library and copying it over.

What I've tried so far:

- Adding a path to **ext_library** in the FILE(GLOB ...) command in the **zephyr_project/zephyr/CMakeList.txt**. This command pulls the
  source files from **zephyr_project/source**, but doesn't seem to like
  either relative or static paths to **ext_library**.
- Adding a CMakeList.txt in the **ext_library** that compiles a static library. This also requires using **add_subdirectory** to the
  zephyr CMakeLists.txt file. This didn't seem to compile the library,
  however, it appears to have found the **ext_library/CMakeLists.txt**.
  The evidence of this is in **zephyr_project/lib** folder which has some CMake folders that are empty but named the same as
  the **ext_library/CMakeLists.txt**. Other evidence is that the
  message(...) commands in both CMakeLists.txt are being printed.
- Using both static and relative paths to the **ext_library** folder.
- Using cmake FILE(COPY ...), the files weren't copied. No apparent error.

What has worked:
Manually copying code from the **ext_library/source** and **ext_library/include** into the appropriate folders in **zephyr_project**.

Additional info:
**zephyr_project/zephyr/CMakeLists.txt** (original + attempt at adding the ext_library as a subdirectory)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13.1)
include($ENV{ZEPHYR_BASE}/cmake/app/boilerplate.cmake NO_POLICY_SCOPE)
project(firmware)

set(EXT_LIB "C:/Users/mcelr/Desktop/project/ext_library")
add_subdirectory(${EXT_LIB} ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})

FILE(GLOB app_sources 
    "../src/*.c*"
)
```

**ext_library/CMakeLists.txt** (CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR does point to the correct directory at runtime, as confirmed via removed message(...) logging)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13.1)
project(ext_lib)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build)
add_library(ext_lib_zephyr STATIC
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/source/packet.c
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/source/checksum.c
)
```

Thank you so much for any advice or hints to solve this,
Austin

Answer (score 0):

I found workaround for it:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13.1)
include($ENV{ZEPHYR_BASE}/cmake/app/boilerplate.cmake NO_POLICY_SCOPE)
project(Project_work_queue)

SET(LIB_PATH ../../libs/)
FILE(GLOB lib_sources ${LIB_PATH}*.*)
FILE(COPY ${lib_sources} DESTINATION ../../../src/libs_tmp)

FILE(GLOB app_sources ../src/*.c*)

include_directories(${LIB_PATH})
target_sources(app PRIVATE 
    ${app_sources}
    )
```

And add src/libs_tmp to .gitignore. I know it is ugly way but it works :-P